# How to draw a curved line chart with CustomPainter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to draw a line graph with some smooth curves, like this one from fl_chart :

[image]

I tried using quadraticBezierTo, but it didn't work :

[image]

This is my code, is there any other way?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DrawLines extends StatefulWidget {
  final Coordinates lineCoordinates;
  final double yHeight;

  DrawLines({required this.lineCoordinates, required this.yHeight});

  @override
  _DrawLinesState createState() => _DrawLinesState();
}

class _DrawLinesState extends State<DrawLines> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      foregroundPainter: LinePainter(
          coordinates: widget.lineCoordinates, yHeight: widget.yHeight),
    );
  }
}

class CoordValues {
  late double x;
  late double y;

  CoordValues({required this.x, required this.y});
}

class Coordinates {
  late CoordValues startCoords;
  late CoordValues endCoords;

  Coordinates({required this.startCoords, required this.endCoords});
}

class LinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  late Coordinates coordinates;
  late double yHeight;

  LinePainter({required this.coordinates, required this.yHeight});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Color(0xFF295AE3)
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 2;

    //curved
    Path path = Path();

    path.moveTo(coordinates.startCoords.x, yHeight - coordinates.startCoords.y);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        coordinates.startCoords.x + 15,
        coordinates.startCoords.y,
        coordinates.endCoords.x + 15,
        yHeight - coordinates.endCoords.y);
    //for every two points one line is drawn

  

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

I think my question is pretty straightforward but somehow stackoverflow wants me to write more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Path drawPath(bool closePath) {
  final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  final height = chartHeight;
  final path = Path();
  final segmentWidth = width / 3 / 2;
  path.moveTo(0, height);
  path.cubicTo(segmentWidth, height, 2 * segmentWidth, 0, 3 * segmentWidth, 0);
  path.cubicTo(4 * segmentWidth, 0, 5 * segmentWidth, height, 6 * segmentWidth, height);

  return path;
}
```

This tutorial is great for this purpose and everything explained well. just check the link below

https://www.kodeco.com/32557465-curved-line-charts-in-flutter

Answer (score -1):

you can use fl_chart dependency here is the link

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).